# Can I add something to a php link via javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have the following link
`http://localhost/benutzerdaten/singleentry.php?id=1`
and would like to add another parameter to the link.
Is this possible? I've tried it with  `.setAtrribute` but this only lets me completely change the link.

Thanks to any responses!

table with the link I want to add something to:

```
        echo "<table align='center' id='ftable' class='ftable'><tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th><<th>E-Mail</th><th>Telefon</th><th>Geburtsdatum</th><th>Straße</th><th>Details</th></tr>";
        // output data of each row
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

            echo "<td></td><tr><td>" . $row["id"] . "</td><td>" . $row["firstname"] ."&nbsp;". $row["lastname"] . "</td><td>" . $row["email"] . "</td>
                <td>" . $row["phone"] . "</td><td>" . $row["birthdate"] . "</td><td>" . $row["street"] . "</td>
                <td><a href='singleentry.php?id=" .$row["id"]."' class='details' id='details'>Details</a></td></tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }
```

my javascript function (used to filter the table in the php)

```
function filterRows() {
    var input, filter, table, tr, td, cell, i, j, h, detailLink;
    input = document.getElementById("filterfeld");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    table = document.getElementById("ftable");
    tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

        for (i = 1; i < tr.length; i++) {

            tr[i].style.display = "none";
            td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
            for (j = 0; j < td.length; j++) {
                cell = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[j];

                if (cell) {

                    if (cell.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                        tr[i].style.display = "";

                        detailLink = cell.innerHTML;
                        if(detailLink.indexOf("href=") && document.getElementById("details").getAttribute('href') != "http://google.at"){
                            var el = document.querySelectorAll('.details');
                            for(h = 0; j < el.length; h++){
                            console.log(el[h].getAttribute('href'));
                            el[h].setAttribute('href',"");
                            console.log(el[h].getAttribute('href'));
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

}
```

Comment: Do you mean in your HTML? Or do you mean in the URL in the browser? Share your markup, share you code

Comment: Not enough information.

Comment: _“I've tried it with .setAtrribute but this only lets me completely change the link”_ - you know that string _concatenation_ is a thing that exists, no …? So set the new attribute value as the old attribute value + 'xyz'  then, “problem” solved.

Comment: (There are more sophisticated ways of doing that, of course - like making use of the fact that every link element also exposes the properties known from the `location` object, so you could access the query string portion only to begin with, and append to that.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [URL API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) to easily modify whatever part of a url you want

```js
const link = document.querySelector('a');
// create url object from element href
const url = new URL(link.href);
// set search parameter value
url.searchParams.set('bar', 1);
// reassign element href property
link.href = url;

// display revised href
console.log(link.href)
```

```html
<a href="http://example.com?foo=1"></a>
```